# Drawing Bezier shapes in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, drawing, bezier

WPF has a nice way of defining complex Bezier shapes by using specific notation, eg.

```
M 0 0 L 10 10 L 0 20 Z
```

Is there a direct or non-direct (eg. with manual parsing) way to draw such shapes in Windows Forms?

To be precise, I am searching for any solution (preferably built in .NET framework), which will accept a path/shape definition and will draw it on given canvas. I'm not interested in manual drawing Bezier curves.

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt9t4wah(v=vs.110).aspx). WPF has a nice way for many things, which are utterly absent in winforms. the real question is why would anyone care to use winforms to begin with.

Comment: Have you thought of using a `Canvas` in a WPF `UserControl` in a WinForms [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) control?

Comment: @Sheridan It won't help me *drawing* shapes (eg. on another control, bitmap etc.)